# Can VS May for possibility

Tags: modality

We use "might/may" to indicate probability:

Example 1:
This trip might be dangerous

We use "can" for something certain, for an objective possibility:

Example 2:
Who knows, it can go either way

Then what is the difference between the following sentences:

Example 3:

a) You can get lost in it

b) You might/may get lost in it

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I believe the answers to the question I linked should help you. If they don't, please [edit] to explain why and we may be able to reopen your question.

Comment: There's a subtle difference between (1) *X **might** be dangerous* and (2) *X **can** be dangerous*. The latter often implies that ***X*** is something *known* (it's happened before, *sometimes* with bad results), whereas the first version is more suitable if ***X*** is something *new* (so it doesn't have a *history* of being dangerous / ending badly, but we don't yet know enough to assume it's safe).I'm not sure that distinction applies to your example 3 though.